# Write data to google spreadsheet from appscript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications, try-catch, httprequest

This is my APP Script code through which I'm trying to append a row to a sheet. It writes the data but then always returns err which triggers a `.fail()` function is JavaScript:

```
   function doGet(e) {
    try {
        var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();;
        var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
        var name = e.parameter.name;
        var address = e.parameter.address;
        var phone = e.parameter.phone;
        var email = e.parameter.email;
        var city = e.parameter.city;
        var quantity = e.parameter.quantity;
        var productTitleFinal = e.parameter.productTitleFinal;
        var productPriceFinal = e.parameter.productPriceFinal;
        var fullDate = e.parameter.fullDate;
        var comment = e.parameter.comment;
        var url = e.parameter.url;
        var rowData = sheet.appendRow([fullDate, name, email, phone, address, city, productPriceFinal, comment, productTitleFinal, quantity, url]);
        var result = "Insertion successful";
        return result
    }
    catch (err) {
        return err
    }
}
```

This is JavaScript code from which sends a request to write data

```
var script_url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbx5_btANVIwai5PJ1CT_VHocfcbIhy-_vViGSg6vzDfE_4hOFg4/exec";

  var url = script_url+"?fullDate="+fullDate+"&name="+name+"&email="+email+"&phone="+phone+"&city="+city+"&address="+address+"&comment="+comment+"&quantity="+quantity+"&productTitleFinal="+productTitleFinal+"&productPriceFinal="+productPriceFinal+"&comment="+comment+"&url="+url;

    var request = jQuery.ajax({
      crossDomain: true,
      url: url ,
      method: "GET",
      dataType: "jsonp",
    })
    .done(function(res){
        console.log(res)
    })
    .fail(function(e){
        console.log(e)
    })
    .always(function(e){
        console.log(e)

  });
```

What could be wrong with this code?

Comment: Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you have issues for my answer yet, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your current situation? I would like to study to solve your issues.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the reason of your issue is that `doGet()` always doesn't return the status 200. In order to avoid this issue, how about the following modification?

### Modified script:

Please modify your script as follows.

#### For Google Apps Script:

From:

```
return result
```

To:

```
return ContentService.createTextOutput(result);  // Modified
```

#### For Javascript:

From:

```
var request = jQuery.ajax({
  crossDomain: true,
  url: url ,
  method: "GET",
  dataType: "jsonp",
})
```

To:

```
var request = jQuery.ajax({
  crossDomain: true,  // Also this might not be required.
  url: url ,
  method: "GET",
  // dataType: "jsonp",  // Modified
})
```

### Note:

- **When you modified the Google Apps Script, please redeploy the Web Apps as new version. By this, the latest script is reflected to the Web Apps. Please be careful this.**
- By the way, in the case of `return err`, the error message is not returned. So if you want to return the error message, please modify to `ContentService.createTextOutput(err)`. But in this case, the status code 200 is returned. So if you want to retrieve the error message as the error, it is required to prepare the script in the function of `done(function(res){})`. Because at the Web Apps of Google Apps Script, the custom status code cannot be used.

### Reference:

- [createTextOutput()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/content/content-service?#createtextoutput)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.